# Data validation for calculated cell

Tags: excel

I'd like to make it so that an error is returned if a calculated cell attempts to go below zero. I have made a vacation day excel sheet so that if a person schedules a vacation day, the total amount of vacation days remaining decrease. The thing is, if I schedule for more days than I have available, the calculated cell for the remaining days will go into the negative values since it is calculated and not user entered. I used data validation on the cell and if I try to manually enter a negative number it wont allow me. I just want the same thing to happen for a calculated cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Validation** is not appropriate for this task, instead use:

```
=IF(your_formula<0,"ERROR",your_formula)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I ended up doing. It gets the job done, but it doesn't completely stop the user from being able to add a valid input that creates the invalid output.

Comment: What you desire would require a macro!

Answer (score 1):

If Column A is Total Vacation Days allowed, Column B is the Total Vacation Days Used, and Column C is the formula =A1-B1, then apply custom data validation to B1. The formula would be =B1<=A1. That should work. It's not applying it to the answer cell, but the input cell creating the error.